# Passing variables (containing spaces) to curl --data field

Tags: json, bash, jq

Arguments containing spaces will not properly pass to the curl command.
Quotes are not passed correctly in the --data field.

If I just echo the variable 'curlData' that I use in the curl command I get everything as it should be; ex :

```
$echo $curlData
'{"name":"jason","description","service"}'
```

I don't understand why curl dont expend this 'curlData' variable as expected:

```
curl --data '{"name":"jason","description","service"}'
```

Here's a sample of my code:

```
read -p "Name : " repoName
read -p "Description []: " repoDescription

curlData="'"{'"'name'"':'"'$repoName'"','"'descripton'"':'"'$repoDescription'"'}"'"

curl --data $curlData $apiURL
```

And the error:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 26
```

Thank your for your help, I feel i'm in Quote-ception right now.

Comment: `echo $foo` is in and of itself buggy. Always use `echo "$foo"`, just as you should quote *every other* expansion, unless you know very specifically why you *aren't* doing so. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)

Comment: ...btw, for that same reason, it's correct to write `echo "The value is: $foo"`, **not** `echo "The value is:" $foo`; even when you're concatenating constant strings and expansion results, you want *both* the string and the expansion to be quoted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, right, that I understant ;-) . Very instructive link btw, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Quote all variable expansions,
2. To make sure that `curlData` is a valid JSON value with properly escaped special-characters etc., use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) for producing it.

```
curlData="$(jq --arg name "$repoName" --arg desc "$repoDescription" -nc '{name:$name,description:$desc}')"
curl --data "$curlData" "$apiURL"
```

Comment: Just using `printf` isn't safe. If `repoDescription='hello", "callbackUrl": "http://evil.com/whatever'`, the user who was supposedly only able to control a description was just able to set a callback URL. And even without malicious intent, you can easily get errors when the result of substituting a string with quotes/spaces/backslashes/etc is invalid JSON.

Comment: @Charles I should remove the printf one then

Comment: +1, now (the jq syntax is terser than mine), but I'd argue that this still is incomplete insofar as it isn't instructing the OP to quote their arguments when calling `curl` (which they weren't, and very much need to).

Comment: @Charles That would make this answer an exact copy of yours, which you posted 2 mins after I edited to add jq solution. You could've edited mine instead of posting a similar one.

Comment: I generally consider it bad form to edit someone else's answer without approval when it's under active maintenance; when I hit save on own jq-based answer, my browser hadn't yet refreshed to show your amendment towards that end. Feel free to amend as-appropriate, though, now that I've removed mine.

Comment: jq works very well! thanks to all of you for your comments and for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, which was very difficult to even understand. I used the below construct in a number of curl commands present in my shell script. It always worked like a charm. Until one fine day I had to pass a variable which was string containing spaces (eg. modelName="Abc def").

```
  curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://localhost:43124/api/v1/devices/'$Id'' \
  -H 'accept:*/*' \
  -H 'Authorization:Bearer '$token'' \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -d '{
  "modelName":"'$modelName'",
  "serialNumber":"'$childSN'"
}'
```

Worked for me after the below change

```
 curl -X 'PUT' \
  'http://localhost:43124/api/v1/devices/'$Id'' \
  -H 'accept:*/*' \
  -H 'Authorization:Bearer '$token'' \
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
  -d '{
  "modelName":'\""$modelName"\"',
  "serialNumber":"'$childSN'"
}'
```

I took help from the accepted answer by @oguz. Pasting this response , just in case anyone is in similar situation

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to any form of package management, I highly recommend `jo`.

```
curlData=$(jo name="$repoName" description="$repoDescription")
curl -d "$curlData" "$apiURL"
```

Comment: jo ? I can't find it, where does it comes from @vintnes ?

using apt

Comment: @dotHello Have you done `apt update`? Using `apt list jo` shows me `jo/stable,now 1.0-1+b1 amd64`

Comment: Well `jo` works very well too! I like the fact that it's syntax is a bit shorter.
Does anyone have some pros and cons using `jo` vs `jq` ?

Comment: @dotHello It adds a dependency. So does `jq`, but that's easier to justify considering you can do everything you need to do with json. It comes down to if and how you're planning to share this code.